# Why must I declare TextField as public, but not Label

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to programming; go easy. :)

I have a simple program (for learning purposes) that won't compile unless I make the two TextField objects public. I'm getting an error (ava.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement can not access a member of class firstjavafxprogram.SampleController with modifiers "private"). And I just can't for the life of figure out why those two have to public but Label can be private. Hope I post my code correctly:

```
package firstjavafxprogram;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    public TextField txtVolts;
    public TextField txtAmps;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        String labelMessage = getTheMessage();
        label.setText(labelMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }  

   @FXML
    private String getTheMessage(){
        String enteredVolts = txtVolts.getText();
        int volts = Integer.parseInt(enteredVolts);

        String enteredAmps = txtAmps.getText();
        int amps = Integer.parseInt(enteredAmps);

        int watts = volts * amps;
        String msgString = "Watts: " + Integer.toString(watts);

        return msgString;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Well, it seems FXMLLoader complaining that they are private and can't be accessible.

Comment: Ah, JavaFX. I will withdraw all comments on this as I am unfamiliar with this, but if it adheres to the javabean model, then you need public setter/getter methods and private fields.

Comment: Note that [this Oracle JavaFX Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) states that `Any class that adheres to JavaBean constructor and property naming conventions can be readily instantiated and configured using FXML. The following is a simple but complete example that creates an instance of javafx.scene.control.Label and sets its "text" property to "Hello, World!":`

Comment: I'm not having any problem getting or setting the text of the Label field, just the TextFields. I guess that's where my confusion is. I don't see why my TextFields have to be public but not the Label.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Change

```
@FXML
private Label label;
public TextField txtVolts;
public TextField txtAmps;
```

### To

```
@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
private TextField txtVolts;
@FXML
private TextField txtAmps;
```

as per this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/FXMLTableViewController.java.html).

Comment: Ahh, it worked! Thanks Jarrod! I knew it would be something simple. After reading the example and a little more poking around, it makes more sense now. Thanks for taking a minute to answer such an elementary question.